# admin registered staff user can't login django admin, form registered staff user can't

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-authentication

When I create a user via django admin panel, and mark it staff it can login django admin page as it should, but when I create user vie `UserForm` and mark it as staff it can not login. It says invalid username password for staff and so on.

I suspect the error is because I am using,

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth','django.core.context_processors.request')
```

Currently I have the following code:

```
user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
    user = user_form.save()
    user.set_password(user.password)
    user.save()
```

As form:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
```

Now tell me, how can I by pass this problem?

Comment: `user.is_staff = True` before saving the user?

Comment: Your context processors have nothing to do with it. The problem is most likely either `user.set_password(user.password)` being called twice (once in `UserForm.save()` and the second time in your view), or `UserForm.save()` not correctly settings the `is_staff` flag. You can easily check the second case by looking at your your user object. For the first one, you didn't post your `UserForm` code so only you can tell...

Comment: is_staff=True yep all cases. I double checked from admin panel too.

Comment: try to remove the line `user.set_password(user.password)`, does that help? Also make sure, that `user.is_staff=True`.

Comment: removed set_password, yet it did not work :(

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers now you can see my UserForm as well at the question.

Comment: And where are you setting the `is_staff` flag exactly ??? You don't have the `is_staff` field in your form and you don't set it in your view neither.  Oh and yes, have you checked your user had the `active` flag set ?

Comment: Actually I have another logic to approve staffs. but I can ensure you that both is_staff is True for both cases (as seen from admin panel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phew, I had to add something like this:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

three simple step:

1. create user:

`user = User.objects.create_user("username")`

1. set password for your user:

   `user.password = "your_password"`

   `user.set_password(user.password)`
2. make user as super user:

`user.is_staff=True`

`user.is_superuser=True'`

3. save your user:

   `user.save()`

now you can login in admin panel of django

**EDIT**:
instead of all above you can do just:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

and create a super user